# Tree to optimize OpenGL Pointcloud

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization

I would like to optimize my OpenGL program. 
It consists in loading a vector of 3D points then applying shaders to them.
But I have billions of points, and my FPS drop to 2 when I try to see the points.

Actually I'm sending every points, and I believe this is what is too much for my computer.

Is making a KD-tree (for example) to store my points and then send to my shaders only the points contained in the viewing frustum an efficient way to optimize my program?

And, since my goal isn't to do research of points, but only use points in the viewing frustum, which tree would be better? Octree? KD-tree?

Comment: `send to my shaders only the points contained in the viewing frustrum an efficient way to optimize my program?` yes. As you state; if it's only for viewing the data. If you have a lot of nearby points, also consider the posibility to adjust the "resolution" of your model so that it comes close to your view resolution. I don't have any examples for that.

Comment: I'm not really only viewing point, but my shaders are working screenSpace, so I don't need all the points. 
Which tree is the best to achieve that ?

Comment: I can't help you with that question :/

Comment: Thanks anyways :)

Comment: You may also want to consider using a simple grid. One, it's simpler to implement, and, two, you just want to identify rough areas that have an intersection with the frustum. You can do that relatively easily with each grid cell.

Comment: Simple grid... I don't even thiought about that. 
But since it's a large point cloud, the grid creation wouldn't be too long? Since I have to check in which grid cell each point lay? (I never used this before, so I don't know :/)

Comment: KD-trees are better for ray-tracing, but octrees are faster to build and more dynamic. I'd probably use a octree in your situation.

Comment: And grid, as Surak Mentionned? What do you think about that?

Answer (score 1):

using trees is definitely a good way to deal with large point clouds. i worked on a point cloud rendering software for a while and we used kd-trees for rendering, and regular voxel grids for analysis.

i don't exactly remember the reasons for/against using an octree, but i guess it depends on the density distribution of your clouds: if you have large point clouds with some small high-density areas, you would have lots of empty cells in the octree, whether for evenly-distributed point clouds, octrees might be simpler. We also had 2.5D maps (from aerial scans: several square kilometers of terrain but only little devation in height) where we used quad trees for some tasks.

also we did not render all the points that were in the frustum, because that degenerates e.g. when you zoom all the way out so the whole point cloud is in the frustum again.

instead, all the inner (non-leaf) nodes in the kd-tree contained a "representative" selection of the points in their children, and we rendered the tree only up to a depth that seemed appropriate depending on the distance from the camera to the bounding volume of each node. this way, for areas that are far away from the camera, you render a thinned out version of the point cloud, an LOD of sorts.

if you want to go fancy: we actually maintained a "front-line" of nodes, that is a line or cut from left to right through the tree up to which all nodes should be rendered. this way we did not need to check each node but only the ones in the cut whether their status ("rendered" or "not rendered") should change. additionally, we had out-of-core point clouds which where larger that the (V)RAM, where we allowed the front to only move farther down the tree if the parent node had been loaded from disk.

kd-trees are a bit harder to build because you need to determine where the split plane is located. for this we used a first pass where we read the locations of all the points in the node, determining the split plane, and then a second pass doing the actual split.

i think we had 4096 points per node (i think we experimented with more and 8k or 16k were fine as well), and did one draw call per node. as long as your point cloud fits in VRAM you can simply put all of it in one large buffer and do draw calls with offsets into that buffer.

Comment: Actually, what I want to achieve is more like a "virtual visit" of a place. My shader are here to disable points that area occluded by others. 
My goal is to create something easy for now, Maybe i'll do something better later. 
My pointscloud are probably not evenly distributed since they represents "common object" such as church, house, ... maybe more complicated but it's always structure and infrastructure.

Comment: if you want something simple and you can afford to do a lot of culling per frame (can be done on the GPU btw :) ), then a simple voxel grid as suggested by Surak of Vulcan might suffice. octrees would be the next step and kd-trees the most sophisticated one, i would say. keep in mind that you might want to have nodes of equal (e.g. 4096) point counts, and that's hard to do with regular grids or octrees. also, do you have an idea how to determine visibility/occlusion in a point cloud? we came to the conclusion that this was too complex due to holes in the rendering.

Comment: I believe yes, this order is cool, i will start with Grid. But there are some things I need to understand about griding (how to do the research, how to label my boundingbox, ...).
Well, I'm not sure this answer your question but what I do is to use the position of the point in screenSpace. When it comes to 2D, you look at neighbors of each points and you look if they can occlude the visibility of the point. You quantify this value and if it exceeds a threshold you mark the point as non visible...

Comment: as far as i understand this doesn't help you with performance since it does not prevent rendering of hidden points, it just makes the output pretty by removing hidden points afterwards, eliminating holes and reconstructing surfaces. btw their section 7 sounds exactly like our kd-tree implementation i described above. also, even in your "virtual visit" scenario you can e.g. put the camera in one corner of the building, looking inwards, and then you see almost everything of the point cloud, making an LOD technique necessary again.

Comment: Yes! This is because it doesn't help me with performance that I need something to help me with, and that's the spirit of my question. 
I read their section 7, but since I'm quite new, and alone, I thought at first that it was a little "too hard" for me. 
That's right too for the LOD. I'll have to see this point too.
It makes me a lot to do ahah

Comment: did you ever work on point cloud that is too large for RAM? How do you handle that? 
Do you think that creating a mapped ordered file (using mmap for example) and call for chunk of file from points that are inside the viewing frustum a good way?

Comment: Our point clouds were usually larger than RAM, and we stored the kd-tree on disk, since re-creating them could take hours for large point clouds. We applied that idea of the "front-line" (still not sure what the correct term here is) on multiple levels: one line closest to the root node that marked those nodes that should be rendered, one line that included all nodes that should be in VRAM, and one for nodes in RAM. Everything that was not in RAM stayed on disk. I have no experience with memory mapped files, sorry.

Comment: Ok! 
Thanks a lot!! :) I'll try to understand it well in order to create something good!

Thanks!